# Java Application Scope

Tags: java, session, web-applications, struts2, scope

During a particular session if I obtain application context and store or change something in application scope, would it become available to all the sessions until the server is rebooted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is one of the goals of application scope.

Answer (score 0):

Until the application is restarted, or the server, yes.

But this kind of thing is trivial to test, you should test it — **no answer** beats a test that you make yourself.